# ¿Cómo seleccionar un RichTextBox actual en C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo un `tabControl` en el cual, en tiempo de ejecución creo pestañas y a esas pestañas les agrego un `RichTextbox`. Pero ahora necesito agregar texto a esos `RichTextBox`.

Mi duda es, ¿cómo selecciono el `RichTextbox` actual?

Comment: Se indiza por el número de orden o por el nombre del control. Podemos mostrarte un ejemplo completo, pero mejor sería que publiques el código que estás utilizando para agregar el `TabControl`, las `TabPages` y los `RichTextBox`, para que podamos darte el **código específico** que solucione tu problema, porque desconociendo tu código podemos darte algo que no sea del todo entendible por ti. Si necesitas ayuda para saber cómo publicar puedes consultar el [help].

Comment: Estas trabajando con [tag:winforms] ?

Comment: Deberías agregar imágenes o el código, para entender que intentas hacer. otra cosa que no me queda claro es que dices ¿cómo selecciono el RichTextbox actual? con actual te refieres a seleccionado? Deverias formular mejor la pregunta. ¿cómo modifico el RichTextbox selecciono?

Answer (score 1):

Pues el verdadero problema es como saber cual es TabItem actual dentro del TabControl, porque, una vez que sabes cual es el TabItem, resulta bastante sencillo obtener el RichTextBox correspondiente.

Hay muchos modos para saber cual es el TabItem actual, pero el mejor modo es registrar un gestor que se ejecute cada vez que el usuario cambia de pestaña y que te indique cual es la nueva pestaña.

También hay muchos modos de registrar un gestor que se ejecute cuando cambia la pestaña, pero mi favorito es usar el [AttachedEvent Selector.Selected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selected.aspx) que esta en Windows.Controls.Primitives. Usando ese evento, sabes con seguridad que solo se dispara cuando el elemento adjunto es seleccionado.

El siguiente ejemplo crea por programa tres TabItem con sus correspondientes RichTextBox y añade un texto de identificación a cada RichTextBox cada vez que se selecciona una pestaña.

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives; //recuerda añadir este using

namespace SelectElementInTab
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
         private TabItem DefineTabItem(string header)
         {
             var tabItem = new TabItem() { Header = header, Content=new RichTextBox() };
             Tab.Items.Add(tabItem);
             Selector.AddSelectedHandler(tabItem, OnTabItemSelected);
             return tabItem;
         }

         private void OnTabItemSelected(object sender,RoutedEventArgs args)
         {
             var item = sender as TabItem;
             if (item != null)
             {
                 var textBox = (RichTextBox)item.Content;
                 textBox.AppendText("Soy el textBox de " + item.Header);
             }
         }

         public MainWindow()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
             DefineTabItem("I");
             DefineTabItem("II");
             DefineTabItem("III");
         }
    }
}
```

Como ves, una vez que sabes el TabItem actual, obtener el RichTextBox es cuestión de hacer un casting desde la propiedad Content.

Si quieres crear los TabItem XAML puedes obtener el mismo resultado con:

```
    <TabItem Header="I" Selector.Selected="OnTabItemSelected">
        <RichTextBox></RichTextBox>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="II" Selector.Selected="OnTabItemSelected">
        <RichTextBox></RichTextBox>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="III" Selector.Selected="OnTabItemSelected">
        <RichTextBox></RichTextBox>
    </TabItem>
```

NOTA. Si de antemano sabes cuantas pestañas tendrás, podrías asignar un gestor específico a cada una, pero eso solo es recomendable cuando la gestión que requiere cada pestaña es muy diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener el control seleccionado del formulario a través de `this.ActiveControl`.

Ejemplo:

```
private void AgregarTexto()
{
    this.ActiveControl.Text = "texto";
}
```

**Nota:** Este código funcionara si es implementado dentro del formulario.
Si lo quieres hacer a través de una clase o en un formulario externo debes utilizar. `activeForm.ActiveControl` en lugar de `this.ActiveControl`.

Para mas información puedes revisar la [documentacion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267252(v=vs.60).aspx) oficial.

Algo mas que puedes hacer con la propiedad `ActiveControl` cambiar el control seleccionado actualmente, de la siguiente forma.

```
this.ActiveControl = Nombre_RichTextBox;
```

Espero que te haya sido de utilidad.